# Why can dynamic binding override name hiding in C++?

Tags: c++, scope, overriding, dynamic-binding, name-hiding

I learnt that inner names hides outer names (so overloading does not cross scope) because name lookup goes before type matching. So I write the following C++ code to play with this rule:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void fcn() {}
};
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void fcn(std::string s) {}
};

Base* bp = new Derived;
bp->fcn();
delete bp;
```

According to the hiding rule, the `Derived::fcn(std::string)` function should hide the `Base::fcn()`. But the above code compiles and runs correctly in defiance of the rule. Does it mean dynamic binding can override the name hiding in C++? The thing is, if I change the type of `bp` to `Derived*`, the hiding rule takes effects by uttering a compiling error:

> 'Derived::fcn': function does not take 0 arguments

Could you please help me explain the phenomenon? Specifically, can dynamic binding override the name hiding as I hypothesized? If so, why does the overriding fail if the pointer is pointing to the derived class? Thank you.

Comment: Name hiding doesn't make the function inaccessible, only its name.  For example, this is also perfectly legal: `Derived d; d.Base::fcn();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name lookup (and overload resolution) happens at compile-time.

Given `bp->fcn`, if the type of `bp` is `Base*`, name lookup will examine the scope of `Base` and then find the name `Base::fcn`. The fact that `bp` is pointing to an object of `Derived` doesn't involve in, neither the scope of `Derived` and then `Derived::fcn`. Dynamic dispatch happens at run-time, if `Derived` has an overrided `Derived::fcn()` it will be called at run-time.

If the type of `bp` is `Derived*`, name lookup will examine the scope of `Derived` and then find the name `Derived::fcn`, then name lookup stops, the scope of `Base` won't be examined further more; name hiding happens.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much!